# How can I convert results$ in the code snippet below to an Observable?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I am new to Rxjs and would help with converting results in the code snippet to an Observable. The aim is to be able to use (results$ | async) in html.

```
this.results$ = this.route.data.pipe(
  filter((d) => d.data.showPayrollRep),
  concatMap(() => this.timeCardService.getPayrollRepresentative())
);
```

Comment: Hello, The result should be already an Observable, What is the issue? Did you try to use {{results$ | async}}?

Comment: I am getting a warning about missing properties. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sharing the warning would help, does getPayrollRepresentative take a parameter?